# How to I make the input types for the first two inputs of the form (shown below), drop down menus?

Tags: html, forms

The form below is connected to a database and I would like the first two inputs in the form to display the data from the database in the form of a drop-down menu. Right now, all three inputs in the form have text entry inputs. I am still learning how to work around HTML and I would like to apologize in advance if this is too trivial of a question. I have searched around the web but couldn't find a clue to my question. Please find the HTML code below:

```
<div id="demo">
   <div class="ui inputs">
      <div class="ui icon input">
         <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Sending From" class="form-control"/><i class="icon-user"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="ui icon input">
         <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Sending To" class="form-control"/><i class="icon-envelope"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="ui icon input">
         <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Weight" class="form-control"/><i class="icon-envelope"></i>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="bus"><a href="#fakelink" class="ui button">Quote</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check out the [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the [`<select>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp).

Take this as an example:

```
<div id="demo">
<div class="ui inputs">
    <div class="ui icon input"> <i class="icon-user"></i>

        <select class="form-control">
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="ui icon input"> <i class="icon-envelope"></i>

        <select class="form-control">
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="ui icon input">
        <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Weight" class="form-control" /><i class="icon-envelope"></i>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="bus"><a href="#fakelink" class="ui button">Quote</a>
</div>
```

Of course your `<option>` tags will be generated dynamically from your database values.

---

Here's a JS Fiddle to play with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/leniel/Dd4m8/

Answer (score 1):

You would use a `select` tag with `option` subtags instead of using an `input` tag:

```
<select>
    <option value="">Sending To</option>
    <option value="5">Blah</option>
</select>
```

Instead of a placeholder, you would use an `option` with its `value` attribute set to a blank string. That way, when validating your form you can tell if the person filling out the form did not choose an option.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G4rur/)

Answer (score -1):

Use **select** tag for the purpose.

See following link http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select3

Comment: You haven't added a link.

Comment: There is a link please check.

Comment: Still no link for me to be honest, may be a glitch in submitting it.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I have a chrome extension that blocks w3schools links. Maybe reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select instead.
Visit http://www.w3fools.com/ for more info.

Comment: @Whitebird you're probably filtering w3schools links because they're all garbage.

Comment: You can also provide a code example as just a link to a developer site isn't that helpful always.